# Plot Feature Importance with top 10 features using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Random Forest model with more than 100 variables. The code below allows me to plot all feature importances.
How can I show the top N feature importances ?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

features = bvsa_train_feature.columns
importances = best_rf.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,100))
plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.barh(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], color='b', align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), [features[i] for i in indices])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
features = bvsa_train_feature.columns
importances = best_rf.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)

# customized number 
num_features = 10 

plt.figure(figsize=(10,100))
plt.title('Feature Importances')

# only plot the customized number of features
plt.barh(range(num_features), importances[indices[-num_features:]], color='b', align='center')
plt.yticks(range(num_features), [features[i] for i in indices[-num_features:])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would select either top 10/20 values from a sorted array

```
important_features = np.sort(importances)[:10]
```

or slice top indices

```
indices = np.argsort(importances)[:10]
```